# extjs customise number of rows to display in Ext.grid.ColumnModel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

How should I customize to change how many rows of the columnmodel table gets displayed in my web app before the table scrolls

```
new Ext.Panel({
    items : [{
        xtype : 'panel',
        id : 'abc',
        height : 250,
        autoScroll : false,
        frame : false,
        items : [{
            xtype : 'editorgrid',
            id : 'abc-grid',
            store : abc.Store,
            cm : abc.Col,
            sm : new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel(),
            height : 100,
            frame : false,
            clicksToEdit : 2,
            stripeRows : true,
            view: gridView,
            viewConfig : {
                headersDisabled : true
            },
            listeners : {
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Your question has way too much text and description and sample code in it.

Comment: here we are using a columnmodel with several columns added and we create a panel. Only few rows gets displayed even though we increase the div or the container of this panel. I think this can be handled only within extjs.

Comment: I didn't find an `xtype:'editorgrid'` in the docs. Please elaborate.

Comment: Well, I just found it...

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Not sure to understand exactly what you need. Is it about the size of the table? If it so, change your  height.

Comment: changing the height did not change the no. of rows displayed before requiring to scroll for the remaining rows